# How do I have my html content scroll underneath my header elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image being used as a header under my head element but the rest of the content does not flow underneath. Here is my CSS for the header,

```
#header {
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  position:fixed;
}
```

The html code for the header,

```
<head>
<title>MyWebPage</title>
<img src="../../Pictures/header.jpg" id="header" />
...
```

This is the basic CSS for the rest of the Body of the html,

```
#main {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

I am not sure if I have to add any styling to either the header or the body to have the contents of the body scroll underneath the header when the user moves up and down the web page since the content scrolls above the header.

Comment: set a higher z-index on the `#header`

Comment: Why did you place an image in the `<head>` section? I think you probably mean to place it under `<header>` in the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First why do you put the image into the head-element? Is that even possible, i don't think so, did you men `<header>`?

The z-index property defines which element over-/underlap each other, the higher the z-index the more will the element be on the top of the hierarchy.

Just set

```
#header {
left:0px;
width:100%;
top:0px;
position:fixed;
z-index: 999;
}
```

and it will be on top.

For more information on z-index check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)